# Running JS doesn't work on page load, but otherwise does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fetching some JSON data to an HTML table using AJAX and jQuery.
The script is generating table rows with table data elements and is working properly.

I need to write another script which will count the number of table rows.

Logically I went with:

```
let rows = $('table tr').length
console.log(rows)
```

Running this on page load (e. g. $(document).ready) outputs a length of 0 to the console.

However, running it on any other event (e. g. click) works and outputs the correct length.

To my understanding, the browser runs the counting script before any of the table rows are loaded. Why does this happen? It appears later in the code than the table generating script.

How do I make it work properly on page load? Cheers.

Comment: The code to fetch the data runs asynchronously. That means the program will fire off the request and then start running other code while it waits for the data to come back. You should look into JavaScript asynchronous code and promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Matthew Herbst said, is totally right. Although since you are using jQuery, and according to the documentation on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ I would suggest that you use the .done function (or alternativelly the success callback).
Examples :

Done method :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/getRows.php",
})
.done(function( data ) {
    // data received
    doWhateverHere(); 
});
```

Success callback :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://example.com/getRows.php",  
    success:function(data) {
      // data received
      doWhateverHere(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped! I used the success callback.

Comment: You can also use the error: function(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown) callback to handle the situations when there is an error contacting the server.

*From the docs :*
When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error."